# MySQL Syntax area and validating between 2 drop-down menus

Tags: php, mysql, syntax-error

I have a site in which logged in users can log battery sales, but I am having a little trouble...

I have two questions:

1. When I go to submit the form, Im getting a error message which reads 'MySQL Error: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use' which occurs just after the 'INSERT INTO npc_sales_list' query and have no idea why.
2. I am also trying to validate the drop down menus ('npc_battery_n_code' and 'npc_battery_other_code') so that if a battery is selected in one drop down, the other will revert to 'None'.

At the moment, if question number 1 can be answered ahead of 2 that would be great but any suggestions are welcome.

```
 <?php //logsale.php
 require_once ('./includes/config.inc.php');
 $page_title = 'Log a sale';
 include ('./includes/header.html');

 if (!isset($_SESSION['sp_user_id'])) {

 $url = 'http://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']
 . dirname($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']);
 // Check for a trailing slash.
 if ((substr($url, -1) == '/') OR (substr($url, -1) == '\\') ) {
 $url = substr ($url, 0, -1); // Chop off the slash.
 }
 $url .= '/login.php'; 

 ob_end_clean(); // Delete the buffer.
 header("Location: $url"); 
 exit(); // Quit the script.
 }
 $users = $_SESSION['sp_user_id'];
 ?>

 <h1>Heading</h1>

 <?php

 if (isset($_POST['submitted'])) {// Handle the form.

 require_once ('mydatabase.php');

 if (!empty($_POST['npc_quantity'])) {
 $quantity = escape_data($_POST ['npc_quantity']);
 } else {
 $quantity = FALSE;
 echo '<p><font color="red">You forgot to enter the Quantity</font></p>';
 }  

 if (!empty($_POST['npc_customer_name'])) {
 $customer = escape_data($_POST ['npc_customer_name']);
 } else {
 $customer = FALSE;
 echo '<p><font color="red">You forgot to enter the Customer Name</font></p>';
 }  

 if (!empty($_POST['npc_registration_no'])) {
 $rego = escape_data($_POST ['npc_registration_no']);
 } else {
 $rego = FALSE;
 echo '<p><font color="red">You forgot to enter the Customer Rego Number</font></p>';
 }  

 if (!empty($_POST['npc_suo_no'])) {
 $suo = escape_data($_POST ['npc_suo_no']);
 } else {
 $suo = FALSE;
 echo '<p><font color="red">You forgot to enter the SUO Number</font></p>';
 }  

 if (!empty($_POST['npc_amb_club_no'])) {
 $repair_order = escape_data($_POST ['npc_amb_club_no']);
 } else {
 $repair_order = FALSE;
 echo '<p><font color="red">You forgot to enter the A-Club number</font></p>';
 }  

 if (!empty($_POST['npc_repair_order'])) {
 $amb_club = escape_data($_POST ['npc_repair_order']);
 } else {
 $amb_club = FALSE;
 echo '<p><font color="red">You forgot to enter the Repair Order</font></p>';
 }  

 if (!empty($_POST['npc_invoice_no'])) {
 $inv = escape_data($_POST ['npc_invoice_no']);
 } else {
 $inv = FALSE;
 echo '<p><font color="red">You forgot to enter the Invoice Number </font></p>';
 }  

 if (!empty($_POST['npc_entry_userdate'])) {
 $inv_date = escape_data($_POST ['npc_entry_userdate']);
 } else {
 $inv_date = FALSE;
 echo '<p><font color="red">You forgot to enter the Invoice Date</font></p>';
 }

 if ($quantity && $customer && $rego && $suo && $repair_order && $amb_club && $inv && $inv_date)  {

 $uid = @mysql_insert_id(); //Get the url ID.
 $query = "INSERT INTO npc_sales_list 
 (npc_item_id , sp_user_id, npc_battery_n_code, npc_battery_other_code, npc_quantity, 
 npc_customer_name, npc_registration_no, npc_suo_no, npc_amb_club_no, npc_repair_order,
 npc_entry_userdate, npc_usertype, npc_points, npc_bonus_points, npc_entry_date)
 VALUES
 ('$uid', '$users', '$_POST[npc_battery_n_code]', '$_POST[npc_battery_other_code]', '$quantity',
 $customer , $rego, $suo, $amb_club , $repair_order, 
 $inv , 'NPC', '5' , '0' , NOW())";
 $result = mysql_query ($query) or trigger_error
 ("Query: $query\n<br />MySQL Error: " .mysql_error());

 if ($result = @mysql_query($query)) {

 //Finish the page.
 echo '<p>The sale with invoice number: <strong>' . $inv . '</strong>       <br />
 is now registered into the system.</p>
 <p>If you would like to log in further sales, please <a href="logsale.php">click here</a></p>
 <p>If you would like to view your sales log, please <a href="viewsales.php">click here</a></p>
 ';
 include ('./includes/footer.html'); // Include the HTML footer.
 exit();

 } else { // If it did not run OK.
 echo '<p><font color="red" size="+1">You could not be
 registered due to a system error. We apologize for any
 inconvenience.</font></p>';
 }

 } 

 } else { // If one of the data tests failed.
 echo '<p><font color="red" size="+1">Please check all manatory fields are complete and try again.
 </font></p>';
 }

 mysql_close(); // Close the database connection.

 ?>                         


 <form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="logsale.php" method="post">


 <table width="520" border="0" cellspacing="3" cellpadding="2">

 <tr>
 <td width="184"><div align="right">NPC Vehicle<span class="style2">*</span></div></td>
 <td width="323"><select  name="npc_battery_n_code" id="npc_battery_n_code">
 <option value="None" 
 <?php if (isset($_POST['npc_battery_n_code']) && $_POST['npc_battery_n_code'] == 'None') 
 {echo 'selected="selected"';} ?>>None
 </option>
 <option value="55D23L" 
 <?php if (isset($_POST['npc_battery_n_code']) && $_POST['npc_battery_n_code'] == '55D23L') 
 {echo 'selected="selected"';} ?>>55D23L
 </option>
 <option value="55D23R" 
 <?php if (isset($_POST['npc_battery_n_code']) && $_POST['npc_battery_n_code'] == '55D23R') 
 {echo 'selected="selected"';} ?>>55D23R
 </option>                                
 <option value="75D23R" 
 <?php if (isset($_POST['npc_battery_n_code']) && $_POST['npc_battery_n_code'] == '75D23R') 
 {echo 'selected="selected"';} ?>>75D23R
 </option>
 </select></td>
 </tr>

 <tr>
 <td width="184"><div align="right">Other <span class="style2">*</span></div></td>
 <td width="323">
 <select  name="npc_battery_other_code" id="npc_battery_other_code">
 <option value="50D20L" 
 <?php if (isset($_POST['npc_battery_other_code']) && $_POST['npc_battery_other_code'] == '50D20L') 
 {echo 'selected="selected"';} ?>>50D20L
 </option>
 <option value="50D20R" 
 <?php if (isset($_POST['npc_battery_other_code']) && $_POST['npc_battery_other_code'] == '50D20R') 
 {echo 'selected="selected"';} ?>>50D20R
 </option>
 <option value="55D23LMF" 
 <?php if (isset($_POST['npc_battery_other_code']) && $_POST['npc_battery_other_code'] == '55D23LMF') 
 {echo 'selected="selected"';} ?>>55D23LMF
 </option>
 <option value="55D23RMF" 
 <?php if (isset($_POST['npc_battery_other_code']) && $_POST['npc_battery_other_code'] == '55D23RMF') 
 {echo 'selected="selected"';} ?>>55D23RMF
 </option>
 </select></td>
 </tr>

 <tr>
 <td><div align="right">Quantity <span class="style2">*</span></div></td>
 <td><input type="text" name="npc_quantity" size="10" maxlength="10" 
 value="<?php if (isset($_POST['npc_quantity'])) echo $_POST['npc_quantity']; ?>" /></td>
 </tr>

 <tr>
 <td><div align="right">Customer name<span class="style2">*</span></div></td>
 <td><input type="text"  name="npc_customer_name" size="30" maxlength="30" 
 value="<?php if (isset($_POST['npc_customer_name'])) echo $_POST['npc_customer_name']; ?>" /></td>
 </tr>

 <tr>
 <td><div align="right">Rego number <span class="style2">*</span></div></td>
 <td><input type="text" name="npc_registration_no" size="10" maxlength="7" 
 value="<?php if (isset($_POST['npc_registration_no'])) echo $_POST['npc_registration_no']; ?>" /></td>
 </tr>

 <tr>
 <td><div align="right">SUO No.<span class="style2">*</span></div></td>
 <td><input type="text" name="npc_suo_no" size="10" maxlength="7" 
 value="<?php if (isset($_POST['npc_suo_no'])) echo $_POST['npc_suo_no']; ?>"/></td>
 </tr>

 <tr>
 <td><div align="right">A-Club ID<span class="style2">*</span></div></td>
 <td><input type="text" name="npc_amb_club_no" size="15" maxlength="7" 
 value="<?php if (isset($_POST['npc_amb_club_no'])) echo $_POST['npc_amb_club_no']; ?>"/></td>
 </tr>

 <tr>
 <td><div align="right">Repair Order <span class="style2">*</span></div></td>
 <td><input type="text" name="npc_repair_order" size="15" maxlength="12" 
 value="<?php if (isset($_POST['npc_repair_order'])) echo $_POST['npc_repair_order']; ?>" /></td>
 </tr>

 <tr>
 <td><div align="right">Invoice No. <span class="style2">*</span></div></td>
 <td><input size="10" name="npc_invoice_no" 
 value="<?php if (isset($_POST['npc_invoice_no'])) echo $_POST['npc_invoice_no']; ?>" /></td>
 </tr>

 <tr>
 <td><div align="right">Invoice Date <span class="style2">*</span></div></td>
 <td><input size="12" name="npc_entry_userdate" maxlength="10" 
 value="<?php if (isset($_POST['npc_entry_userdate'])) echo $_POST['npc_entry_userdate']; ?>"/>  </td>
 </tr>

 <tr>
 <td></td>
 <td><input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" /></p><input type="hidden" name="submitted" value="TRUE" />
 &nbsp;</td>
 </tr>
 </table>
 </form>

 <p>Footer</p>


 <?php
 include ('./includes/footer.html');
 ?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is in response to question 1:

You don't appear to have matching columns with values in your SQL:

```
$query = "INSERT INTO npc_sales_list 
 (npc_item_id // get rid of this
```

I think you want to get rid of that first column, so you'll want to do:

```
$query = "INSERT INTO npc_sales_list 
 (sp_user_id, npc_battery_n_code, npc_battery_other_code, npc_quantity, 
 npc_customer_name, npc_registration_no, npc_suo_no, npc_amb_club_no, npc_repair_order,
 npc_entry_userdate, npc_usertype, npc_points, npc_bonus_points, npc_entry_date)
 VALUES // so on and so forth...
```

In the SQL insert statement, if you count the number of columns you have and compare with the number of values you have, you'll notice a mismatch (15 vs 14 which means that the npc_item_id is not necessary, and is probably an auto-incremented unique key anyway).

Comment: Thanks Stegrex, I'll try that and get back

Comment: Silly me, I didn't realize that the VALUES were missing single(') quotation marks, my apologies everybody! Very sorry!